# Mongoose - How to set default value if new value is not in available enum list

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have the following schema:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  profile: {
    name: {
      type: String,
      default: "",
      enum: ["", "Mike", "John", "Bob"]
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to ensure that when a `user.save` action is triggered and provided `name` variable is not in the list of available `enum` values, validation does not fail, but sets the value to `default`.

For example, in Node:

```
User
  .findById(req.user.id)
  .then(user => {
    user = Object.assign(user, { name: "Sam" })
    return user.save()
  })
```

This will fail validation with **`Sam` is not a valid enum value for path `profile.name`**, but the ask is to have value fallback to an empty string:

```
{
  name: ""
}
```

I tried tapping into Mongoose pre validate hook, but cannot seem to access provided values and documentation has not been helpful.

Comment: what if you simply added the default to the list of available enum values? so `enum: ["", "Mike", "John", "Bob"]`

Comment: That will not solve the issue, since save explicitly tries to set a value that is not in the list of acceptable values

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use a [pre save hooks](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html)

```
var schema = new Schema(..);
schema.pre('save', function(next) {
    // verify here
    next();
});
```

Comment: Problem here is that validation ("validate" pre hook) happens prior to "save" pre hook, and thus save will fail without even getting to `// verify here` bit -- http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#order